# Filter database records by Date range

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sybase-asa

I have a database system which allows users to create records. At the point of posting the record to the table it captures the current date and time.

I have a form which allows users to filter/search for records.

What is the best way to allow filtering for the Dates of the records. Like StartDate an EndDate?

The below is what I do when capturing the DateTime for the record.

**FieldByName('logged_dt').AsDateTime := now;**

Comment: Are you storing dates in the DB in textual form?

Comment: ive edited my question, i was wrong about what i am doing when capturing the date/time

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because the error message you're getting now is a different issue. You can not make a major change to the question that changes it's entire meaning after you've received answers to it. If you now have a new issue, create a new question and ask about it there. I've answered the question you asked here, which is how to filter records by a date range.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do so is by using SQL with parameters and a `WHERE` clause:

```
Query.SQL.Clear;
Query.SQL.Add('SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, DateCol');
Query.SQL.Add('FROM TableA');
Query.SQL.Add('WHERE DateCol >= :StartDate');
Query.SQL.Add('AND DateCol <= :EndDate');
Query.ParamByName('StartDate').AsDateTime := StartDateYouWant;
Query.ParamByName('EndDate').AsDateTime := EndDateYouWant;
Query.Open;
if Query.IsEmpty then
  ShowMessage('No records found in that range')
else
  // Do whatever with the rows found
```

An alternative syntax is to use `BETWEEN`, which would change the `WHERE` clause to

```
Query.SQL.Add('WHERE DateCol BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate');
```

I've run across issues with using `BETWEEN` with DATETIME columns because of the time portion of the value, and (in my own experiences) using the `>=` (GTE) and `<=` (LTE) operators works more easily. Your mileage may vary, so you should test and decide which works best for you with your particular DBMS and data.